# How to show members in Session with repeater?

Tags: c#, session, repeater, datalist

I log members in on my master page and have this code on my memberListing.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptmembers" runar="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="MemberName"><%# Eval("strName") %></div>
        <div class="MemberSurname"><%# Eval("strSurname")%</div>
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        popMembers();
    }
}

protected void popMembers()
{
    DataTable dtMembers = clsmembers.GetMemberList();
    StringBuilder sbMember = new StringBuilder();

    rptmembers.DataSource = dtMembers;
    rptmembers.DataBind();
}
```

this works fine for displaying a list of members from the DB , but how can I show all members in session ? , by wrapping that around a if statement ....

```
if(clsMembers = (clsmembers)Session["clsmembers"] == dtMembers) //// some sort of check 
{
    // when show members in session with repeater
    // when the session dies the member will not be shown in list till he logs back in
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a list of members stored in session the easiest way to bind it to a repeater is to:

- Create variable of type `BindingList<Member>` where Member is a class with strName and strSurname fields
- Fill it with items from collection stored in session (dtMemebers?)
- Bind `BindingList` to repeater eg. `rptMembers.DataSource = memeberBindingList`

Easier solution would be to store BindingList in session, then it would suffice to:

```
if(null != Session["clsMembers"])
{ 
   rptmembers.DataSource = (BindingList<Member>)Session["clsMembers"];
   rptmembers.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Session is not available from data-binding expressions (<%# %>) , so this is definitely the right answer. You should bind in the code-behind, not within the expression syntax. You have to use Eval(). Calling a server-side function is fine, but the function won't have access to session. It has to be in the datasource, to be eval()'d. I'm guessing the callstack excludes databinds from inclusion of session (start/stop called beforehand)

Comment: Yup. 
It even says [right here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls). You have to manually call DataBind during the appropriate execution context (ie page load), instead of using the DataSourceID attribute in the aspx element.